# Trouble debugging user access to Windows SMB shares

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, network-share, server-message-block

I am having trouble with 2 PC of my domain, both on Windows 10 1909, which I'll call "01" and "02", using a domain service account (called "s_automate" to connect to a SMB share on the network. The share is working and networking connectivity is OK, as pings works and all ports are open.

Here's the trouble : The account "s_automate" has a "Access is Denied" error on both 01 and 02.

Details :

- Connecting a network drive with specific logins using an admin account inside the "s_automate" session doesn't work, with the same "Access is Denied" error.
- But having Windows sessions on either PC 01 or 02 with an administrator account grants access to the SMB share.
- Rights have been correctly configured, as double-checked. But even if an account had no rights, it should access the SMB share anyway under our "Everyone","BUILTIN/Users" and "Domains/Users" Read/Write policy.
- Logs collected though graylog doesn't seems to show any errors.
- Using Windows Credentials with different accounts having access on other computers doesn't work on 01 & 02.
- 01 & 02 are in the same OU as other computers which doesn't have the problem. No GPO blocks them, and GPOs are updated.

It's my first time posting here, so I'm open to give more detailed info. I wish to understand where to look up to find the error and access the SMB with this account.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've hit most of the pain points for a Windows network share, but have you checked the NTFS permissions on the folder? Those often get overlooked but still are required to allow access.

Comment: Hi, NTDS permissions are OK but what are pain points ? 
I'm trying to check if a session using this user is already "blocked" on a file or somerthing, so far nothing